# Excel VBA code inputing the correct numbers

Tags: string, vba, excel

```
For innerLoop = 0 To addRowOffset = 1
    Range("C" & countRow & ":" & "C" & (countRow + addRowOffset)).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range("B" & (4 + innerLoop)).Value
Next
```

So I have this code which is supposed to take some rows that I inserted into a sheet, and fill Colum "C" with the a range of strings from the "Template" sheet. However, all it does it put one string and copy over and over again into the cells. How, do I get this to put the entire range of strings into the other sheet?

I'm willing to provide more of the code, or information if needed.

Comment: If you're using variables for ranges, another way to write the range is using Cells() - just a note.  You can replace your range with `Range(Cells(countRow,3),Cells(countRow+addRowOFfset,3))`.  As you use variables, and especially when using integers to refer to columns, Cells() might be easier to use/read than Range("A" & [num]...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be putting the same value from the Template worksheet into all of the Range("Cx") cells at once. You put different values in but you replace all of the Range("Cx") cells each time during the loop.

```
For innerLoop = 0 To addRowOffset
    Range("C" & countRow + innerLoop).Value = _
      Sheets("Template").Range("B" & (4 + innerLoop)).Value
Next innerLoop
```

That should put a different value into a different cell for each iteration of the loop.

Note the change in `For innerLoop = 0 To addRowOffset` as well.